# Spring Boot thymeleaferror when using jar file to run

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This question has been asked before but I did not solve my problem and I getting some weird functionality.

If I put my index.html file in the template directory under resource like so:

```
├─ src
│   ├─ main
│   │  ├─ java
│   │  │   └ com
│   │  │       └ pic
│   │  │           └ name
│   │  │               ├ config
│   │  │               ├ controller
│   │  │               ├ domain
│   │  │               ├ dto
│   │  │               ├ error
│   │  │               ├ formatter
│   │  │               ├ repository
│   │  │               ├ service
│   │  │               └ utils
│   │  └ resources
│   │    ├ static
│   │    │   ├ css
│   │    │   ├ fonts
│   │    │   ├ images
│   │    │   └ js
│   │    └ templates
│   │      ├ index.html  
│   │      ├ admin
│   │      ├ error
│   │      └ fragments
```

and this is pom file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

when I execute proj in idea works with no problem. but when execute jar this error returned:
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the preceding slash `/` while accessing your view. Here is why.

When you run the application from an IDE, The classes and resources are not packaged as a JAR. This means the file system does most of the job in loading and maintaining path resolution and stuff for all the resources. Due to this a classpath resource with names `classpath*:/templates/index.html` and `classpath*:/templates//index.html` are the same.

However once it's packaged as the spring boot JAR file, It's the spring boot ClassLoader's responsibility to load the classes and resources from the compressed JAR file. Unfortunately this one doesn't see `double slashes` as `single slash`.

**To avoid the issue, drop the slash prefix from your view names.**

There is also a [**bug entry**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1744) against spring-boot project for the same.

Comment: You're a life saviour! I spent the whole day meddling with all sorts of solutions working out what's going wrong with heroku deployment and almost driven mad! Thank you so much!